# Video out over USB?

Tags: usb, video-out

I'm starting to regret not getting an Atrix - the whole docking scheme seems so cool. Unfortunately, it seems that I can't even do much of a DIY thing to output a video stream with the device's screen over USB. I have a rooted G2.

The G1 could do video-out, but only because it had the hardware for it (although it was never implemented). There's apps out there for VNC and for screenshots, although not for screen recording (from which it would be a small step to output to USB).

The most frustrating thing is that this is an area with very sparse documentation. Stuff like this hasn't much been done before, and I can't find any existing software to do this sort of thing.

Is there anything that you guys know of that I could follow for developing an app to do this via software since the hardware for video-out isn't there? Even better yet, is there any software that can record the screen? If I was on a Linux desktop, how could I tap into the monitor's video stream?

Thanks,
-Trey

Comment: Development questions belong on StackOverflow, though they'll need you to ask a specific question (not "How can I develop an app").  Please see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I don't think that this is necessarily a question for Stack Overflow. "How can I capture the video output of my device?" seems like a valid question for here, although I'm not sure there's going to be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a question to StackOverflow. I asked a very similar question about a week ago, and basically, the answer is no, to implement that you'll have to dig very deep into the code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155292/get-current-frame-from-android-mediaplayer) for more. Hope it fits your question.